# Как правильно сделать выборку SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Приветствую Уважаемые! Имеется вот такой SQL запрос:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM visit WHERE dateTime BETWEEN '$dateStart' AND '$dateEnd' ORDER BY dateTime DESC";
```

Данный запрос делает выборку по диапазону даты, дата в формате 2016-10-11 00:41:08
Пробую и с DESC и с ASC, но результат один и тот же - строки сортируются по возрастанию, т.е. сначала самые старые записи, а необходимо чтобы в начале отображались самые последние записи по дате и времени. Помогите пожалуйста с запросом, не могу найти правильный ответ. Благодарю за внимание!

Comment: Какой тип у поля dateTime? Не CHAR ли?

Comment: Я просто оставлю это здесь, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511882/sorting-by-date-time-in-descending-order

Comment: тип поля - datetime

Comment: Так все таки, как мне правильно составить запрос? Помогите мне пожалуйста. В этой теме stackoverflow.com/questions/9511882/sorting-by-date-time-in-descending-order я ничего не понял.

Comment: Очень странно, у меня такой запрос сортирует даты и по возрастанию и по убыванию (правда бд MySQL)... А если взять поле dateTime в кавычки: \`dateTime\`?

Comment: @КиноТрейлеры,результат тот же?

Comment: Ой, хотя эти кавычки только для mysql вроде... для sql попробуйте так:
SELECT * FROM visit WHERE [dateTime] BETWEEN '$dateStart' AND '$dateEnd' ORDER BY [dateTime] DESC

Comment: @Ksenia, Ваш вариант такую ошибку показывает - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[dateTime] BETWEEN '2016-10-11' AND '2016-10-12' ORDER BY [dateTime] DESC' at line 1

Comment: @КиноТрейлеры, а, так у вас mysql - тогда нужно SELECT * FROM visit WHERE \`dateTime\` BETWEEN '$dateStart' AND '$dateEnd' ORDER BY \`dateTime\` DESC

Comment: @КиноТрейлеры, и добавьте, пожалуйста, в пост результат этого запроса у вас...

Comment: @Ksenia, Благодарю! Помогло ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема решается экранированием поля `dateTime` - так как в mysql это зарезервированное слово:

```
SELECT * FROM visit WHERE `dateTime` BETWEEN '$dateStart' AND '$dateEnd' ORDER BY `dateTime` DESC;
```